# Changing function behavior based on the given argument in Python

Tags: python, function, arguments

I have a function that plots histogram subplots from an array of numbers.

I want to change the "bins" based on the argument I passed to the function. If I pass "X_arr" I want the step size of arange to be 1; and 10 if I pass Y_arr. And of course similar behavior for the filenames. I have more than 100 arrays that follows a pattern, so passing a kwarg won't be feasible.

If I do something like the following, it throws `FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison` error. I know that the argument "array" is interpreted as the numpy array it was passed to; I don't know how to make the code to take it as the word "array".

```
def plot(array): 

    if array == 'X_arr':
        bins = np.arange(0,int(np.amax(array)+1),1)
        filename = 'hist_X.png'

    elif array == 'Y_arr':
        bins = np.arange(0,int(np.amax(array)+1),10)
        filename = 'hist_Y.png'

    -some plotting here-

    plt.setp(axs, xticks=bins)

    plt.savefig(filename)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. If the argument is a numpy array, why are you comparing it to a string? How is that supposed to work?

Comment: Are `X_arr` and `Y_arr` the names of global variables and you want to compare the array to those? Then get rid of the quotes.

Comment: @Barmar, "How is that supposed to work?" I don't know, that's why I am asking here. I am plotting the `X_arr` as `plot(X_arr)`. If I pass `X_arr`, I want bins step size to be 1, and 10 if I pass `Y_arr`. I don't know how I can be clearer than this.

Comment: So `X_arr` is a variable name, not a string. If you want to know if two variables are equal, why would you put one of them in quotes? Just `if array == X_arr:`

Comment: @Barmar: Yes, of course it is a variable. I basically want to compare the argument I gave to this `plot` function with a string of this argument itself. I have 100s pairs of `X` and `Y` types of arrays I need to plot, so I can't simply change the bin step size every time.

Comment: Does that mean you'll have hundreds of `elif` statements in the function?

Comment: @Barmar: No, there is another function that reads these two kinds of arrays with `np.loadtxt()` from corresponding set of files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the quotes so you compare variables, not strings.

And use `is` to tell if the variables refer to the same objects, since you can't compare numpy arrays with `==`.

```
def plot(array): 

    if array is X_arr:
        bins = np.arange(0,int(np.amax(array)+1),1)
        filename = 'hist_X.png'

    elif array id Y_arr:
        bins = np.arange(0,int(np.amax(array)+1),10)
        filename = 'hist_Y.png'

    -some plotting here-

    plt.setp(axs, xticks=bins)

    plt.savefig(filename)
    plt.show()
```

However, this is very poor design, as it means this function can only be used with those two specific variables. You should design things more generally, such as passing another argument that indicates the plotting method.

Comment: Indeed I want this function to be used only with these two kinds of specific variables. `X_arr` and `Y_arr` are two sets of arrays. I have 100s pairs of these arrays. By the way this raises `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Comment: I changed it to `is` instead of `==`.

Comment: I don't know how it didn't occur to me to use `is`. Thank you, now this is what I was looking for.